# what's the best way to format an xml string in ruby?

Tags: xml, ruby, formatting

given an xml string like this:

```
<some><nested><xml>value</xml></nested></some>
```

what's the best option (using ruby) to format it into something readable like:

```
<some>
  <nested>
    <xml>value</xml>
  </nested>
</some>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
require "rexml/document"
include REXML

source ='<some><nested><xml>value</xml></nested></some>'
doc = Document.new( source )
doc.write( targetstr = "", 2 ) #indents with 2 spaces
puts targetstr
```

The #write writes to anything that takes <<(string), so this is valid too:

```
doc.write( $stdout, 2 )
doc.write( an_open_file, 2 )
```

Answer (score 4):

just noticed that [builder](http://rubygems.org/gems/builder) has an `indent` option to do this. but please post your answers as well. not everyone who wants to do this uses builder. also there may be faster solutions for xml strings that you didn't create yourself.