# format an xml string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, formatting

given an xml string like this :

```
<some><nested><xml>value</xml></nested></some>
```

what's the best option(using ruby) to format it readable like :

```
<some>
  <nested>
    <xml>value</xml>
  </nested>
</some>
```

*I've found an answer here: [what's the best way to format an xml string in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465911/whats-the-best-way-to-format-an-xml-string-in-ruby), which is really helpful. But it formats xml like:*

```
<some>
  <nested>
    <xml>
      value
    </xml>
  </nested>
</some>
```

*As my xml string is a little big in length. So it is not readable in this format.*

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the [REXML::Formatters::Pretty](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/rexml/rdoc/REXML/Formatters/Pretty.html) formatter:

```
require "rexml/document" 
source = '<some><nested><xml>value</xml></nested></some>'

doc = REXML::Document.new(source)
formatter = REXML::Formatters::Pretty.new

# Compact uses as little whitespace as possible
formatter.compact = true
formatter.write(doc, $stdout)
```

Answer (score 33):

What about using nokogiri?

```
require 'nokogiri'
source = '<some><nested><xml>value</xml></nested></some>'
doc = Nokogiri::XML source
puts doc.to_xml
# <?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<some>\n  <nested>\n    <xml>value</xml>\n  </nested>\n</some>\n
```

Comment: Even shorter would be ```puts Nokogiri::XML(source).to_xml```

Comment: To remove <?xml version="1,0"?>, just puts `Nokogiri::XML(source).root.to_xml`

Comment: This version just added XML node and leave other nodes in one line in my XML. REXML version formatted all lines. My xml: `<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><SmbBureau xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><bureauRequest xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SMB_WS" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><a:FINAL_RATING i:nil="true"/><a:FRAUD>N</a:FRAUD><a:INTERNAL_OPERATION_NUMBER i:nil="true"/><a:STATUS>CORRECT_ANSWER</a:STATUS></bureauRequest></SmbBureau></s:Body></s:Envelope>`

Comment: When use doc.to_xml again returning String format only. Can u guys help me on this . I want to display attribute values